# Unity show post build data in game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, post-build

I am trying to show post/pre build data to user in the unity game, something I want to update whenever I process a build. turns out in unity, the updated file version after pre or post build is not included in assets. It still fetches the data before pre/post build script.

Can someone help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run prebuild script and call AssetDatabase.Refresh()